# Mermaid problem (OOP)

Tags: object-oriented, c++, object-oriented-design

A Mermaid is half fish and half human. It has upper human body and lower fish body. When under water its upper part swims like a human while its lower part swims like a fish. Please explain how can it swim like a human and a fish at the same time? Create C++ program using class(es) and OOP paradigm to solve this problem.

Note: I don't want the actual code but instead I wanna know the OOP Concepts that can be be used to solve this problem (like multiple inheritance, Composition & Aggregation, Overriding etc...) and why?

The question is how can we make a class "Mermaid" that depicts both human and fish functionality on upper and lower parts of its body (like Inheriting the properties of human and fish on the upper & lower parts of the body respectively). I don't need to know how the functionality would be performed.... Instead the concepts required to satisfy those properties (like swimming like humans and fish at the same time). So forget about the physics part. And as far as the content goes I just copy pasted the question from the OOP paper.

An example "It might be the answer actually" Just an example try:

```
Class Human{ 
/*some data members go here */ 
public:
 void swim()
{ /*functionality */ }
 }; 

Class Fish{
/*some data members go here */ 
public:
 void swim()
{ /*functionality */ }
 };

Class Mermaid:public Human, public Fish{ 
/*some data members go here */
public:
 void someFunction()
{ /*functionality */ }
 }; –
```

Comment: Hint: virtual inheritance.

Comment: how? please explain

Comment: my above code can be completely wrong (maybe it should use composition or something else etc...)........ Its just an example to show how can it be solved.... OK! So please write a comprehensive answer and explain the reason to why you chose that particular technique. Good luck!

Comment: it looks just as broad as [previous deleted question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/280137/mermaid-problem-oop)

Comment: I am not downvoting this because user ar27111994 doesn't have any reputation to lose.  I will check again in a month, and if he has any reputation, *then* I will downvote this.

Comment: As a programming(ish) question, this is one that is far too broad as it touches far too many areas of OOP basics. We need you to fully describe what you understand the answer to be (this doesn't mean copy and paste some OOish code) and how multiple inheritance, composition, aggregation, overriding, and the like apply to it. Then it would be possible for us to guide you to a better understanding of these concepts. But without that initial description from you, the answers can go anywhere and those make poor content.

Comment: why is it being down voted or put on hold? Its a genuine programming question taught in our universities to teach OOP Concepts. And hey, I have also provided you with the sample answer (which also happens to be the one taught at our universities).
@MikeNakis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Mermaid is neither a human nor a fish, so I would not try to shoehorn these classes into an inheritance hierarchy:

```
Class Mermaid{
/*some data members go here */ 
public:
 void swim()
 { /*functionality */ }
 };
```

Implement "swim" as you like. If you want to reuse some code in all 3 implementations of swim, you could easily do this by creating a fourth class like `SwimTools` where you can place that code.

Of course, you might consider to create an interface class `ISwimmer` with an abstract `swim` method and derive `Human`, `Fish`, and `Mermaid` from that class. If you do this should depend on having a practical requirement of dealing with those three classes uniformly.

In C++, you can also combine "interface inheritance" with "implementation inheritance", name the base class "Swimmer" and put the reusable parts there instead of using a separate `SwimTools` class (however, it is debatable if that is a better or worse design).

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse OO classes and ontological classifications. You might naively want to classify a mermaid as both human and fish, but the description of the problem suggests that its swimming behaviour results in the composition of its two parts. OO classes are a means of combining state variables and behaviours which operate on those variables, they package up what something does not describe what something is.

I'd create a Swimmer class, which has two SwimmingBehaviour components - superior ( upper body in humans and merfolk, head end of fish) and inferior ( legs in human, tail in fish and merfolk ). There would be subtypes of swimming behaviours representing human upper body, human legs, fish body, fish tail, and the three types of swimmer would be creating them with different compositions.

Comment: Then what about having two classes human upper body and fish lower body. Then, create two objects of human upper body and fish lower body classes as data members of mermaid class and aggregate swim functionality of human upper body and fish lower body classes into Mermaid swim function.......... @PeteKirkham

Comment: @ar27111994 If the only difference between 'mermaid class' and 'human class' is that a mermaid has different values for some of its properties, you're defining classes to change configuration not behaviour.